# Creating Dictionary from JSON Object and retreive key and value

Tags: json, json.net, deserialization, uipath

I have a JSON string as following:

```json
{
    "UAT": {
        "single account creation": {
            "form validator": {
                "selector": {
                    "anchor": {},
                    "nav": {},
                    "element": {
                        "html": {
                            "title": "Create Single User Account"
                        },
                        "webctrl": {
                            "id": "licenseid-inputEl",
                            "aaname": "License:",
                            "tag": "INPUT"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "javascript": {}
            },
            "license": {
                "selector": {
                    "dropdown": {
                        "button": {
                            "anchor": {},
                            "nav": {},
                            "element": {
                                "html": {
                                    "title": "Create Single User Account"
                                },
                                "webctrl": {
                                    "id": "ext-gen1075",
                                    "aria-role": "button",
                                    "tag": "DIV"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "menu": {
                            "anchor": {},
                            "nav": {},
                            "element": {
                                "html": {
                                    "title": "Create Single User Account"
                                },
                                "webctrl": {
                                    "id": "boundlist-1039-listEl",
                                    "tag": "DIV"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "item": {
                            "anchor": {},
                            "nav": {},
                            "element": {
                                "html": {
                                    "title": "Create Single User Account"
                                },
                                "webctrl": {
                                    "tag": "LI",
                                    "parentid": "boundlist-1039-listEl",
                                    "aaname": "{0}"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "javascript": {}
            },
            "city": {
                "selector": {
                    "textbox": {
                        "textbox": {
                            "anchor": {
                                "webctrl": {
                                    "id": "textfield-1029-labelEl",
                                    "tag": "LABEL",
                                    "aaname": "City:"
                                }
                            },
                            "nav": {
                                "up": "2"
                            },
                            "element": {
                                "html": {
                                    "title": "Create Single User Account"
                                },
                                "webctrl": {
                                    "tag": "INPUT",
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "aaname": "City:",
                                    "id": "textfield-1029-inputEl"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "javascript": {}
            },
            "country": {
                "selector": {
                    "dropdown": {
                        "button": {
                            "anchor": {},
                            "nav": {},
                            "element": {
                                "html": {
                                    "title": "Create Single User Account"
                                },
                                "webctrl": {
                                    "id": "ext-gen1083",
                                    "aria-role": "button",
                                    "tag": "DIV"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "menu": {
                            "anchor": {},
                            "nav": {},
                            "element": {
                                "html": {
                                    "title": "Create Single User Account"
                                },
                                "webctrl": {
                                    "id": "boundlist-1039-listEl",
                                    "tag": "DIV"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "item": {
                            "anchor": {
                                "webctrl": {
                                    "id": "countryCombo-labelEl",
                                    "tag": "LABEL",
                                    "aaname": "Country:"
                                }
                            },
                            "nav": {
                                "up": "8"
                            },
                            "element": {
                                "html": {
                                    "title": "Create Single User Account"
                                },
                                "webctrl": {
                                    "tag": "LI",
                                    "aaname": "{0}"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "javascript": {}
            },
            "region": {
                "selector": {
                    "dropdown": {
                        "button": {
                            "anchor": {},
                            "nav": {},
                            "element": {
                                "html": {
                                    "title": "Create Single User Account"
                                },
                                "webctrl": {
                                    "id": "ext-gen1083",
                                    "aria-role": "button",
                                    "tag": "DIV"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "menu": {
                            "anchor": {},
                            "nav": {},
                            "element": {
                                "html": {
                                    "title": "Create Single User Account"
                                },
                                "webctrl": {
                                    "id": "boundlist-1039-listEl",
                                    "tag": "DIV"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "item": {
                            "anchor": {
                                "webctrl": {
                                    "id": "countryCombo-labelEl",
                                    "tag": "LABEL",
                                    "aaname": "Country:"
                                }
                            },
                            "nav": {
                                "up": "8"
                            },
                            "element": {
                                "html": {
                                    "title": "Create Single User Account"
                                },
                                "webctrl": {
                                    "tag": "LI",
                                    "aaname": "{0}"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "javascript": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, **country**, **city**, **licence**, **form validator** etc are the name of elements which has two property i.e. *selector* and *javascript*. Now I want to traverse any of these elements and get the values of the properties as a string.

For example: if I want to get the string for city->textbox->textbox the output will look like:

```
<html title='Create Single User Account'/>
<webctrl id='textfield-1029-labelEl' tag='LABEL' aaname:'City:'/>
<nav up='2'/>
<webctrl tag='INPUT' type='text' aaname='City:' id='textfield-1029-inputEl' />
```

Again, if I want to get the string for license->dropdown->button the output will look like:

```
<html title='Create Single User Account'/>
<webctrl id='ext-gen1075' aria-role='button' tag='DIV' />
```

The logic behind this is:

1. The first line will contain the *html* value from the *element* inside the traversed path (city->textbox->textbox or license->dropdown->button)
2. Then the *anchor* value will be in place and incase the *anchor* value is blank, it will skip it.
3. Then same for *nav*, if the value is present then it will be placed after *anchor* otherwise it will be skipped.
4. The last line will consists the *webctrl* values inside the *element*. This value will always be present.

I have deserialized the JSON strin using Newtonsoft.Linq.JSON and got a JObject variable. I have traversed the path for city->textbox->textbox as

```
JObject("UAT")("single account creation")("city")("selector")("textbox")("textbox")
```

or license->dropdown->button as

```
JObject("UAT")("single account creation")("license")("selector")("dropdown")("button")
```

and received a Jtoken variable as say myJToken. Now I am unable proceed further to deduce the properties and get the values to concat and create my desired string. Can anyone help me with this please. I am using UiPath to do this, hence no option of creating custom class and deserialize the JSON string and parse it.

For better understanding the key of JSON string is in *italic* and the custom Element that I am looking for is in **bold.**

Comment: Really interesting way of building selectors to use JSON, not something I've seen before

Comment: @Conor I had to find this way as the web application I'm trying to automate has four different departments and the ID of the elements changes department to department though the structure remains same. Instead of building 4 different automations, I am trying to build one dynamic automation and put the differences in this JSON so that I can use dynamic selectors in my automation depending on which department it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `JObject("UAT")("single account creation")("city")("selector")("textbox")("textbox")` will return the following which you are wanting to parse into a string to use as a selector for your UiPath activity. So the JSON below will become:

```
<html title='Create Single User Account'/>
<webctrl id='textfield-1029-labelEl' tag='LABEL' aaname:'City:'/>
<nav up='2'/>
<webctrl tag='INPUT' type='text' aaname='City:' id='textfield-1029-inputEl' />
```

```
{
  "anchor": {
    "webctrl": {
      "id": "textfield-1029-labelEl",
      "tag": "LABEL",
      "aaname": "City:"
    }
  },
  "nav": {
    "up": "2"
  },
  "element": {
    "html": {
      "title": "Create Single User Account"
    },
    "webctrl": {
      "tag": "INPUT",
      "type": "text",
      "aaname": "City:",
      "id": "textfield-1029-inputEl"
    }
  }
}
```

So To build the first selector I have the following:
[image]

3 assigns within UiPath

`strJSONString = your JSON string`

`JOb = JObject.PArse(strJSONString)`

`strSelector = "<html title='" + JOb("UAT")("single account creation")("city")("selector")("textbox")("textbox")("element")("html")("title").ToString + "'/>"`

Followed by 2 if Statements with assigns in them to account for the 2 optional sections *anchor* and *nav*

`if JOb("UAT")("single account creation")("city")("selector")("textbox")("textbox")("anchor").Children.Count > 0`

`strSelector = strSelector + "<webctrl id='" + JOb("UAT")("single account creation")("city")("selector")("textbox")("textbox")("anchor")("webctrl")("id").ToString + "' tag='" + JOb("UAT")("single account creation")("city")("selector")("textbox")("textbox")("anchor")("webctrl")("aaname").ToString + ":/>"`

`if JOb("UAT")("single account creation")("city")("selector")("textbox")("textbox")("nav").Children.Count > 0`

`strSelector = strSelector + "<nav up='" + JOb("UAT")("single account creation")("city")("selector")("textbox")("textbox")("nav")("up").ToString + "'/>"`

Finally followed by an assign for the last webctrl section

`strSelector = strSelector + "<webctrl tag='" + JOb("UAT")("single account creation")("city")("selector")("textbox")("textbox")("element")("webctrl")("tag").ToString + "' type='" + JOb("UAT")("single account creation")("city")("selector")("textbox")("textbox")("element")("webctrl")("type").ToString + "' aaname='" + JOb("UAT")("single account creation")("city")("selector")("textbox")("textbox")("element")("webctrl")("aaname").ToString + ":' id='" + JOb("UAT")("single account creation")("city")("selector")("textbox")("textbox")("element")("webctrl")("id").ToString + "' />"`

This gives the followign selector

```
<html title='Create Single User Account'/>
<webctrl id='textfield-1029-labelEl' tag='City::'/>
<nav up='2'/>
<webctrl tag='INPUT' type='text' aaname='City::' id='textfield-1029-inputEl' />
```

Comment: Brill, would you mind marking the answer as correct please if it works